# Lebesgue measurability of $f \circ T$ when $T \notin GL_n(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

If $f$ is a Lebesgue measurable function on $\mathbb{R^n}$ and for a linear map $T$ such that $T \notin GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is $f \circ T$ Lebesgue measurable?
Also what if $f$ is Borel measurable function?

I do know $T$ is continuous since it is a linear map. I'm confused because since $T \notin GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ we cannot write $(f \circ T)^{-1} = T^{-1} \circ f^{-1}$ and thus can't conclude if it takes a Borel/Lebesgue measurable set back to a Borel/Lebesgue measurable set.

Comment: You can still write that statement about inverses, they just are not actual inverse functions.